# What is the source ip dest ip source mac and dest mac in Gratuitous ARP response

Tags: networking, router, tcp, mac-address, arp

So I am sitting at host A. And I need to send Gratuitous ARP response to Host B. in Gratuitous ARP response I dont know the mac address of Host B my computer on LAN. But can I add 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF to my dest  host B mac address and I know the ip which is 192.168.10.21 so This should be the dest ip address. And my source address for mac and source ip can be any thing so its a flaw in arp. so it should be always mine Host A address. Is this correct understanding. So If I implement userspace tcp can I send Gratuitous ARP response to update my router and dest machine. is this also correct understanding or not? And is it ok to sendGratuitous ARP response between hosts on my broadband  router. is this allowed? both hosts are my computers with my provided internet router

---

Also why I need this? I like to create ebpf XDP filter that drops these packets at target host. All unwanted packets. This is not as much about networking as it is about Ebpf XDP. If I create protection on server then how to test it? I need simulation of these incoming packets. Basically stopping ddos at very beginning at arp level. Mainly for learning ebpf XDP working. If u tell me alternative testing method then I will try that instead of sending these packets to my target host which will my computer as well.

Update

. I can use my router that's not Broadbands router. Also why I need this? I like to create ebpf XDP filter that drops these packets at target host. All unwanted packets. This is not as much about networking as it is about Ebpf XDP. If I create protection on server then how to test it? I need simulation of these incoming packets. Basically stopping ddos at very beginning at arp level. Mainly for learning ebpf XDP working. If u tell me alternative testing method then I will try that instead of sending these packets to my target host which will my computer as well.

Comment: Sorry, what? Could you edit your question with a more on-point description and improved formatting?

Comment: I like to know in gratuitous arp. Can arp reply contain destination address 0xff.

Comment: Please explain why you think you "need to send Gratuitous ARP response to Host B." and the in-built ARP handling on your OS (which you didn't specify) is not enough for you. In particular if you are talking about your home network ("my broadband router"), you never need to do that.

Comment: @dirkt ok sounds good. I can use my router that's not Broadbands router. Also why I need this? I like to create ebpf XDP filter that drops these packets at target host. All unwanted packets. This is not as much about networking as it is about Ebpf XDP. If I create protection on server then how to test it? I need simulation of these incoming packets. Basically stopping ddos at very beginning at arp level. Mainly for learning ebpf XDP working. If u tell me alternative testing method then I will try that instead of sending these packets to my target host which will my computer as well.

Comment: All my host are on my network LAN

Comment: Added comment explaining circumstances to question. (Please edit the question yourself the next time, comments are not guaranteed to stay around).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I like to create ebpf XDP filter that drops these packets at target host.

You usually cannot do this without OS integration, because the only difference between a gratuitous ARP response and a normal ARP response is that the OS sent out an ARP request before. On Linux, the behaviour of the kernel wrt. to GARP can be controlled by the sysctl

```
arp_accept - BOOLEAN
    Define behavior for gratuitous ARP frames who's IP is not
    already present in the ARP table:
    0 - don't create new entries in the ARP table
    1 - create new entries in the ARP table

    Both replies and requests type gratuitous arp will trigger the
    ARP table to be updated, if this setting is on.

    If the ARP table already contains the IP address of the
    gratuitous arp frame, the arp table will be updated regardless
    if this setting is on or off.
```

See `/usr/src/linux/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt` for a list of sysctls like this one.

It *might* be possible to replicate this with eBPF, but why do that if the kernel can already do it?

> If I create protection on server then how to test it? I need simulation of these incoming packets.

You can simulate ARP responses with `arpping`.

> If u tell me alternative testing method

Instead of somehow trying to use your home network router, make as many network namespaces as you want on your Linux machine (google how to do that), connect them up with a veth pair into the main network namespace, join them all in one bridge, and then you have "virtual network" with as many devices as you need. Now you can observe real ARP requests and responses (use `tcpdump` or `wireshark`), and what the Linux kernel does with different settings, and what effects your eBPF rules have (if you still need them).

Comment: Well this is what I want. I don't want to disable arp. But disable only gratuitous arp. So need to do with XDP. Wishing I could find out all our out going arp requests. And store them in Ebpf Map. And if any response does not have matching request I and drop it.  Can it be done with XDP.

Comment: Read again: That option doesn't "disable ARP". It only disables **gratuitous ARP** (it ignores ARP requests and responses that don't already have an entry in the ARP table, because "this" machine has not done an ARP request, and these are the gratuitious requests/responses). So, no, you don't need to do it with XDP. But suit yourself...

Comment: So if I disable this then will I be protected from DDoS

Comment: If your DoS threat model consists of local machines flooding your LAN segment with gratuitous ARP requests/responses, then yes, your machine will ignore those. However, they'll still consume bandwidth. Also, the usual DDoS consists of machines hammering your server, which has **nothing at all** to do with ARP requests. If your end goal is to "protect you from DDoS", please open a new question, and describe what kind of DDoS you expect. (And as an exercise, try to understand why ARP is not involved in normal scenarios).

Comment: So DDoS can be triggered on LAN. Do websites connected to LAN Hosted on server. I believe there must be other local IPs

Comment: I belive ddos can only be stopped at LAN level if we go with what's available on OS. In case of ICMP flood. If my gratuitous arp disabled then this can be prevented. Because I checked sending ICMP ping requests from spoofed IPs with out arp Table entry does not work system ignores them tested with Local host and as well as LAN. I mean sending ICMP ping without arp Table entry for mac and ip of spoofed ip